# Error: 'NA' does not exist in current working directory (Webscraping)

Tags: r, web-scraping, na

I am trying to web-scrape data from the following url-:
https://university.careers360.com/colleges/list-of-degree-colleges-in-India
I want to click on each college name and get particular data for each college.

First what I did was to collect all the college urls in a vector-:

```
#loading the package:
library(xml2)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

#Specifying the url for desired website to be scrapped
baseurl <- "https://university.careers360.com/colleges/list-of-degree-colleges-in-India"

#Reading the html content from Amazon
basewebpage <- read_html(baseurl)

#Extracting college name and its url
scraplinks <- function(url){
   #Create an html document from the url
   webpage <- xml2::read_html(url)
   #Extract the URLs
   url_ <- webpage %>%
   rvest::html_nodes(".title a") %>%
   rvest::html_attr("href")  
   #Extract the link text
   link_ <- webpage %>%
   rvest::html_nodes(".title a") %>%
   rvest::html_text()
   return(data_frame(link = link_, url = url_))
}

#College names and Urls
allcollegeurls<-scraplinks(baseurl)
```

Working fine uptill now, but when I use read_html for each url, it is showing an error.

```
#Reading the each url
for (i in allcollegeurls$url) {
  clgwebpage <- read_html(allcollegeurls$url[i])
}
```

> Error: 'NA' does not exist in current working directory ('C:/Users/User/Documents').

I even used 'break' command but still same error-:

```
#Reading the each url
for (i in allcollegeurls$url) {
  clgwebpage <- read_html(allcollegeurls$url[i])
  if(is.na(allcollegeurls$url[i]))break
}
```

Please help.

Posting str of allcollegeurls as requested-:

```
> str(allcollegeurls)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   30 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ link: chr  "Netaji Subhas Institute of Technology, Delhi" "Hansraj 
College, Delhi" "School of Business, University of Petroleum and Energy 
Studies, D.." "Hindu College, Delhi" ...
 $ url : chr  "https://www.careers360.com/university/netaji-subhas- 
 university-of-technology-new-delhi" 
"https://www.careers360.com/colleges/hansraj-college-delhi" 
"https://www.careers360.com/colleges/school-of-business-university-of- 
 petroleum-and-energy-studies-dehradun" 
"https://www.careers360.com/colleges/hindu-college-delhi" ...
```

Comment: I am new to R, so kindly explain accordingly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `allcollegeurls` have a `url` column? haven't run the code as I'm not sure of the legal implications of scraping this site. Could you add the `str` of allcollegeurls?

Comment: yes it has a url column !! Just written the structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This work,

```
purrr::map(allcollegeurls$url, read_html)
```

map function: The map functions transform their input by applying a function to each element and returning a vector the same length as the input. I love to avoid `for` use in R.

Comment: Jut load `purrr`. No need for the entire `tidyverse` for one function.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing almost the same issue with my data today.
Please remove any `NA` from the url.

In my case the error was

> Error: ' ' does not exist in current working directory.

I removed blanks from the columns on which the function was applied and it worked.
The error above shows that there are `NA` on which the function cannot be applied.