# 'NA' does not exist in current working directory (webscraping with for loop)

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to web scrape the data from the tables of all German cities from this webpage (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Orte_mit_Stolpersteinen#Deutschland). With the first 5 steps, I get the urls from all the cities, which works fine.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(rlist)
library(stringi)
library(htmltab)
library(foreign)

#1 url Germany 
url = "https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Orte_mit_Stolpersteinen#Deutschland"

#2 get url endings of all Cities
city_urls = url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '//td[7]/a') %>% 
  html_attr("title")

#3 subset German url endings 
city_urls = as.data.frame(city_urls[19:1013])

#4 concatenate url start and endings
URLs_germany = c()
for (cities in city_urls) {      
  URLs_germany <- paste0('https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/', cities, '') 
}

#5 correction of urls -> add missing "_" between the words 
Stolpersteine_cities = as.factor(str_replace_all(URLs_germany, " ", "_"))
```

The problem occurs at step 6. With this for loop I want to get all the data from the respective pages as well as the geo data. If I execute it, I get the error “NA doesn’t exist in current working directory”.
I’ve seen the related page on stackoverflow ([Error: 'NA' does not exist in current working directory (Webscraping)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54513282/error-na-does-not-exist-in-current-working-directory-webscraping)), but I couldn’t apply the mentioned solutions on my case.

```
#6 loop through all 
for (i in Stolpersteine_cities) {
  
  city <- read_html(i)
  
  sample <- city %>%
    html_node(xpath = '//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table') %>% 
    html_table()
  
  #find geolocation
  geo_link <- city %>%
    html_node(xpath = '//*[@text()="Standort"]')%>% 
    html_attr("href")
  
  geo_links <- city %>%
    html_nodes("table") %>% 
    # html_nodes("thead") %>% 
    html_nodes("tbody") %>% 
    html_nodes("tr") %>% html_nodes("td") %>% 
    html_nodes("small") %>%
    html_nodes("a") %>%
    html_attr("href")
    
  long_lat_list <- vector("list", nrow(sample)) 
  #find geo location
  for(k in 1:length(geo_links)){
    
    geo_info <- read_html(geo_links[k])
    
    lat <- geo_info%>%
      html_node(xpath = '//span[@class="latitude"]')%>%
      html_text()
    
    long <- geo_info%>%
      html_node(xpath = '//*[@class="longitude"]')%>%
      html_text()
    
    long_lat_list[[k]] <- list(latitude=lat, longitude=long)
    
  }
  
  sample$latitude <- lapply(long_lat_list, "[[", 1)
  sample$longitude <- lapply(long_lat_list, "[[", 2)
  
  #Save City X 
  saveRDS(sample, "filename.Rds")
  
}
```

I then tried to execute the for loop with just the first 4 cities/urls. While the first two urls work, the third url leads to the mentioned error. But I couldn’t identify any differences in the tables on Wikipedia and I don’t really get what’s the problem.

I would be grateful for any help you’re able to provide.

Comment: I suppose that the URL for the third city is wrong. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Achim_(Landkreis_Verden)  Wouldn't it be easier to directly extract the link from the table and not create it manually in step #4 and #5

Comment: This is the url of the city. I need the url with the list of the "Stolpersteine". So for the third city it would be: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Stolpersteine_in_Achim If you click on the list symbol in the 7th column you get to it. There shouldn't be any mistake to that. And I guess that also answers your question, as I cannot extract the link directly from this list symbol.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't try out your code on my work machine. If you're interested on the locations, perhaps check out openstreetmap, which should provide a more stable API to request the geo locations. https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/DE:St%C3%A4dte_mit_Stolpersteinen and there's also a way to access it with R.

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring at the line `geo_info <- read_html(geo_links[k])`. The issue is that `geo_links` is empty. So when you do `1:length(geo_links)` it returns the vector `c(1, 0)` and goes into the for `for` loop.

Then, in `geo_info <- read_html(geo_links[k])` it tries to access the first element of the vector `geo_links`. Since the vector is empty, it returns `NA`. When `read_html` tries to read this `url` it returns this error message (I think it is trying to read the "file" NA in the working directory).

So you should test for the length of `geo_links` and only enter the for loop if `length(geo_links) > 0`.

```
  if (length(geo_links) > 0) {
    for(k in 1:length(geo_links)){
      
      geo_info <- read_html(geo_links[k])
      
      lat <- geo_info%>%
        html_node(xpath = '//span[@class="latitude"]')%>%
        html_text()
      
      long <- geo_info%>%
        html_node(xpath = '//*[@class="longitude"]')%>%
        html_text()
      
      long_lat_list[[k]] <- list(latitude=lat, longitude=long)
      
    }
    
    sample$latitude <- lapply(long_lat_list, "[[", 1)
    sample$longitude <- lapply(long_lat_list, "[[", 2)
  }
```

The reason you are getting empty lists in some of these links is because the tables are not exactly the same between the different links.

You look for the geolocation data in nodes with the tag "small". It works in the first two, but it does not in the third one. In the 3rd one there is no "small" node and the geolocation data is tagged differently...

Answer (score 0):

This is just a quick proof of concept, that you can also get the same data from the OpenStreetMap database using R. Not completely worked out, since I tried it for the first time, but should get you started and seems to me to be a better way, since the data structure is more well-behaved.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(osmdata)
library(data.table) 


q <- getbb("Baden-Baden") %>%
  opq() %>%
  add_osm_feature(key = "historic",
                  value = "memorial") 
str(q) 

result <- osmdata_sf(q)

dt <- result$osm_points %>% data.table() 
  
dt[memorial.type == "stolperstein",]
```